# Bug in solr's isWithin operator for geo spatial filtering?

Tags: solr, geospatial, solrj, solr5

Consider following document in solr index.

```
{
        "id": "580ddd10a5a18387fba12f1b5805374872931533336fa0ce",
        "conceptid": "580ddd10a5a18387fba12f1b",
        "storeid": "5805374872931533336fa0ce",
        "startTime": "2016-10-21T15:36:08Z",
        "endTime": "2016-10-24T15:36:08Z",
        "update": "2016-10-24T15:36:08Z",
        "conceptLocations": [
          "POINT (-82.540283 40.15736)", (p1)
          "POINT (-54.316406 -16.056371)" (p2)
          "POLYGON (.....) " (pl1)
        ],
        "concept_name": [
          "event6"
        ],
        "tags": [
          "Tag 2g",
          "Tag 2a"
        ],
        "_version_": 1549065073902747600,
        "score": 1
}
```

This document has two points stored in multivalued field `conceptLocations` so the points are stored in an array. Thus, if we do a query with filter which matches ***any one*** of these points then this document should be returned. Similarly, if we do a query with filter `tags:"Tag 2a"` then also this document should be returned i.e. for a multivalued field any one value should match for document to be selected. This is working fine with all the multivalued fields except the `conceptLocations` field in case of `isWithin` operator.

For conceptLocations field, no documents are returned if we do following kind of query.

`conceptLocations: "IsWithin( Polygon around point p1 only  )"  // doesn't return document`

Ideally, since one value of conceptLocations matches with filter, the document should be returned. Interestingly, it works fine with Intersects operator. The query,

`conceptLocations: "Intersects( Polygon around point p1 only )"  // returns document`

returns the document as expected.

Also, following if we use geoWithin with a polygon which covers both p1 and p2 then the document is returned.

```
conceptLocations: " IsWithin( Polygon covering both p1 and p2 )"   // returns document
```

I am not sure if this is a bug in solr but following standard rules of filtering the document should be returned even if only one value of a multivalued fields matches with the filter. Any idea why that is not the case here or am I missing something? Solr version is 5.0.0.